# MsiEnumProduct not listing all installed product

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Trying to get the list of all installed product using MsiEnumProduct with admin privileges but found that it's not listing all, few product it missed. Below the is the code I used.

Below are the functions used to enumerate the installed product and get the details of product like name, version, location and publisher.

```
bool MsiQueryProperty(LPCTSTR szProductCode,
LPCTSTR szUserSid,
MSIINSTALLCONTEXT dwContext,
LPCTSTR szProperty, wchar_t* szValue, DWORD valueSize)
{
    DWORD cchValue = 0;
    UINT ret2 = ::MsiGetProductInfoEx(
        szProductCode,
        szUserSid,
        dwContext,
        szProperty,
        NULL,
        &cchValue);

        if (ret2 == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cchValue++;
           if (cchValue <= valueSize)
          {
             ret2 = ::MsiGetProductInfoEx(
            szProductCode,
            szUserSid,
            dwContext,
            szProperty,
            (LPTSTR)szValue,
            &cchValue);
          }
        }

      return true;
}

void MsiEnum()
{
    UINT ret = 0;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    TCHAR szInstalledProductCode[39] = { 0 };
    TCHAR szSid[128] = { 0 };
    DWORD cchSid;
    MSIINSTALLCONTEXT dwInstalledContext;
do
{
    memset(szInstalledProductCode, 0, sizeof(szInstalledProductCode));
    cchSid = sizeof(szSid) / sizeof(szSid[0]);

    ret = ::MsiEnumProductsEx(
        NULL,           // all the products in the context
        _T("s-1-1-0"),  // i.e.Everyone, all users in the system
        MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_USERMANAGED | MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_USERUNMANAGED | MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_MACHINE,
        dwIndex,
        szInstalledProductCode,
        &dwInstalledContext,
        szSid,
        &cchSid);

    if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wchar_t name[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
        MsiQueryProperty(
            szInstalledProductCode,
            cchSid == 0 ? NULL : szSid,
            dwInstalledContext,
            INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLEDPRODUCTNAME, name, BUFSIZ);

        wchar_t publisher[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
        MsiQueryProperty(
            szInstalledProductCode,
            cchSid == 0 ? NULL : szSid,
            dwInstalledContext,
            INSTALLPROPERTY_PUBLISHER, publisher, BUFSIZ);

        wchar_t version[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
        MsiQueryProperty(
            szInstalledProductCode,
            cchSid == 0 ? NULL : szSid,
            dwInstalledContext,
            INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING, version, BUFSIZ);

        wchar_t location[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
        MsiQueryProperty(
            szInstalledProductCode,
            cchSid == 0 ? NULL : szSid,
            dwInstalledContext,
            INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION, location, BUFSIZ);

        dbg_print(L"Installed Program Name:%s", name);
        dbg_print(L"publisher:%s", publisher);
        dbg_print(L"version:%s", version);
        dbg_print(L"location:%s", location);

        dwIndex++;
    }

   } while (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Not all programs are installed with msi

Comment: does it means it list only those product which are installed using MSI ?

Comment: Not sure. There are a lot of legacy install techniques that are still supported. What are you trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to list all installed program in the system by all users, after this problem I used registry to fetch list of installed program.